# Adaptive Issuance: `edge_of_baking_over_staking` parameter

Tags: adaptive-issuance

Could you please сlarify regarding the `edge_of_baking_over_staking` parameter? Are bakers able to set this percentage manually, are there any limitations for bakers on the percentage or is it set automatically?

This part of an [article](https://medium.com/the-aleph/a-walkthrough-of-tezos-new-staking-mechanism-4ff0c50a57a8) just sounds confusing in that it's not clear how rewards coming from stakers will be divided:

> "It is not possible for a public baker to freeze their 15% edge. It is always unfrozen. Likewise, they may not decide to do different things with the rewards coming from their own state vs their stakers; it is all divided in the same fashion."

Answer (score 1):

Bakers are able to set the `edge_of_baking_over_staking` manually. Any value between 0 (0%) and 1 (100%) is allowed.

Let's look at specific examples. Let's say that you are a baker with 10,000 tez and you have a staker staking 10,000 tez with you. If you set `edge_of_baking_over_staking` to:

- 100% (the default): all earnings from staking go to the bakers' free balance. Then:

  - the baker's frozen balance does not change: it is always 10,000 tez
  - the baker's free balance increases with all the rewards due to the baker's stake AND the staker's stake
  - the staker's frozen balance does not change: it is always 10,000 tez. The staker earns nothing (and should unstake).
- 0%: all earnings from staking stay in the frozen balance. Then:

  - the baker's frozen balance increases as the baker participates in consensus
  - the staker's frozen balance also increases, by the same amount
  - the baker's free balance does not increase: the baker gains nothing from accepting stakers: they are offering a free service. (they still earn more operation fees from more baking slots, which are not shared with stakers)
- 15% - a reasonable value for any public baker. Then, each time the baker earns a reward from staking, the following happens:

  - 15% of this reward goes to the free balance. This is the baker's "edge" that they shall keep, for their service of accepting stakers,
  - the remaining 85% are split equally between baker and staker and are frozen.

The examples above exclude **delegation rewards**: if the baker has some free balance, and/or delegators, they get delegation rewards, which accrue to the free balance.

If the baker has set their edge to 15%, they can have up to 3 sources of rewards:

- rewards from their own frozen balance: this one is always frozen
- the edge they are collecting from their stakers: this one is always going to the free balance
- rewards from delegation:  this goes to the free balance. The baker is expected to redistribute them with TRD, TAPS, TezPay etc.

Under adaptive issuance, frozen balance gives more baking rights than the free balance. Therefore, a public baker accepting stakers will accumulate tez in their free balance over time. The will likely want to freeze this extra tez from time to time, by running the `stake` operation, in order to earn more.

A baker might wish to do one of the following:

1. have the edge accrue to the frozen balance (so they compound automatically)
2. have the bakers rewards from their own stake accrue to the free balance (so they can sell them without waiting for the unfreeze period)

However, under the current implementation (Oxford protocol), this is not possible.